# How to read the Xamarin iOS Heaviest stack for the target process?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, crash

I don't know if this is a valid question or not but I am stuck hence I am here for guidance.

So my app is `Xamarin` `iOS` app is crashing but I don't know whats causing it.

I have identified the flow due to which it crashes. But still haven't identified the correct cause of it.

I have the crash logs provided by iOS Device Log but I have no idea what is causing the issue

**I only know is that it is being killed by CPU usage**

```
Event:            cpu usage
Action taken:     none
CPU:              90 seconds cpu time over 170 seconds (53% cpu average), exceeding limit of 50% cpu over 180 seconds
CPU limit:        90s
Limit duration:   180s
CPU used:         90s
CPU duration:     170s
Duration:         169.88s
Duration Sampled: 157.34s
Steps:            44
```

The logs are :

```
Heaviest stack for the target process:
  44  ??? (libdyld.dylib + 6144) [0x19093b800]
  44  ??? (MyApp.iOS + 714604) [0x1025fa76c]
  44  ??? (MyApp.iOS + 29476604) [0x1041686fc]
  44  ??? (MyApp.iOS + 27632748) [0x103fa646c]
  44  ??? (MyApp.iOS + 28574860) [0x10408c48c]
  44  ??? (MyApp.iOS + 28549584) [0x1040861d0]
  44  ??? (MyApp.iOS + 27772120) [0x103fc84d8]
  44  ??? (MyApp.iOS + 4407332) [0x102980024]
  44  ??? (MyApp.iOS + 714772) [0x1025fa814]
  44  ??? (MyApp.iOS + 15211316) [0x1033cdb34]
  44  ??? (MyApp.iOS + 15211436) [0x1033cdbac]
  44  ??? (MyApp.iOS + 15897920) [0x103475540]
  44  ??? (UIKitCore + 10504576) [0x194bba980]
  44  ??? (GraphicsServices + 13196) [0x19b00d38c]
  44  ??? (CoreFoundation + 667276) [0x190ab3e8c]
  42  ??? (CoreFoundation + 669056) [0x190ab4580]
  42  ??? (CoreFoundation + 667908) [0x190ab4104]
```

**How to even read this?**

**What is causing the issue?**

Comment: Hi , do you know where code modified compare to the last successful building ?  And  you also can show the output of vs here to check .